# LibGDX How can I scale a slider

Tags: java, libgdx, lwjgl

Im working on an app like flappy bird and I have 2 sliders (for the sound and volume)
But when I try to do:

`slider.scale(float X, float Y)` it doesnt scale and nothing happens.
I cant interact with the slider when I scale it, so I think uts scaled but rendered normally.

I rendered it like this:
slider.draw(batch, 1);
I cant render it with the scale

I want to scale the background and the knob, how can I do that?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [LibGDX scale a slider, HOW?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41940854/libgdx-scale-a-slider-how)

Answer (score 2):

For performance reason most scene2d.ui groups have transform set to false by default.

For more detail you can check 
https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Scene2d.ui#rotation-and-scale

If you want to scale you can use Container which is useful for setting the size and alignment of a single widget.

```
@Override
public void create() {
    stage=new Stage();
    Skin skin=new Skin(Gdx.files.internal("skin/uiskin.json"));

    Slider slider=new Slider(0,100,1,false,skin);

    Container<Slider> container=new Container<Slider>(slider);
    container.setTransform(true);   // for enabling scaling and rotation
    container.size(100, 60);
    container.setOrigin(container.getWidth() / 2, container.getHeight() / 2);
    container.setPosition(100,200);
    container.setScale(3);  //scale according to your requirement

    stage.addActor(container);
}

@Override
public void render() {
    super.render();

    Gdx.gl.glClearColor(1,1,1,1);
    gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

    stage.draw();
    stage.act();
}
```