# LibGDX scale a slider, HOW?

Tags: java, libgdx

How can I scale a slider in LibGDX?

Im trying to scale a slider with:

slider.scale(10); (for example)

but when I try that i cant interact with the slider that leads to me thinking that the slider ist scaled but rendered normally. I render it with slider.draw(batch, 1);

Has anyone got an idea?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For performance reason most scene2d.ui groups have transform set to false by default.

For more detail you can check

https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Scene2d.ui#rotation-and-scale

If you want to scale you can use Container which is useful for setting the size and alignment of a single widget.

```
@Override
public void create() {
    stage=new Stage();
    Skin skin=new Skin(Gdx.files.internal("skin/uiskin.json"));

    Slider slider=new Slider(0,100,1,false,skin);

    Container<Slider> container=new Container<Slider>(slider);
    container.setTransform(true);   // for enabling scaling and rotation
    container.size(100, 60);
    container.setOrigin(container.getWidth() / 2, container.getHeight() / 2);
    container.setPosition(100,200);
    container.setScale(3);  //scale according to your requirement

    stage.addActor(container);
}

@Override
public void render() {
    super.render();

    Gdx.gl.glClearColor(1,1,1,1);
    gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

    stage.draw();
    stage.act();
}
```

Comment: How can I scale the knob and the background of the slider?